# How to modify Keras Layers after training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I have loaded a pretrained ResNet (see code below) and want to reproduce a paper where the authors wrote:

> Then, we decrease the stride of the first convolutional layers of the conv5 bank from 2 px to 1 px to prevent down-sampling. Next, we add holes to all 3x3 convolutions in conv5 to preserve their receptive field. This reduces the stride of the full CNN to 16 px. [DeeperCut: A Deeper, Stronger, and Faster Multi-Person Pose Estimation Model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03170)

Is this possible with a pretrained ResNet and if, how is it done in keras?

My current code:

```
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

x = base_model.output
x = Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=[3, 3], strides=2, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(x)
pred = Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=[3, 3], strides=2, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=pred)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

How would I modify the conv5 bank here? Or do I have to train a completly new network for this?

Comment: Being it a static graph, I suppose it's very hard to do it. Really. The suggestion is to copy the code from resnet, change the target layer before creating the model, create the resnet, if you have specific weights you trained, transfer the weights (don't change the layer structure, number of channels, etc, only a few parameters can be changed using the same weights)

Comment: But modifying the stride should not make a big difference, because filter sizes and weights can stay the same, can't they? Or can I load the weights of the pretrained model into a custom designed ResNet with only a different stride in the last layer?

It was also possible to do this with googles slim tools in TF 1.3 (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_utils.py)

Comment: Yes, you can, that's what I'm suggesting. What is difficult is to change anything in a static graph.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, my bad.